# Code to play videos in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Can anyone help me how to play videos in windows phone.

I have displayed all my videos in list box.And when i click on a particular video immediately it should be navigated to other page and play.When i click on a particular video it is navigating to other page but not playing.I was getting no errors and even warnings also.

Xaml code in navigated page:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="player" AutoPlay="True"/>
```

Xaml.cs code in navigated page:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred! Please verify your internet connection.");
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
             else
            {

            string songcode = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("songcode", out songcode))
            {
                var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(songcode, YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
                player.Source = url.Uri;
            }
```

I was a beginner in windows phone apps.

please anybody help me with this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="player" AutoPlay="True" MediaOpened="player_MediaOpened"/>


 private void player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        player.Play();

    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried  it even though only blank screen was displayed.Video is not playing.

Comment: @deepu are u doing it on Emulator ? Might only works with device , i think so . pls make sure your video is in correct format [Format Supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_VideoSupport)

Comment: Yes i was doing it on Emulator.

Comment: I tried to implement this in my program, using c++ but I get a identifier "object" is undefined. Same with "player"